# Left Exclusion Join when data extension has composite primary key

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql

I have a query on writing left exclusion joins when the data extensions has the composite primary key.

I have below two data extensions
DE1

| ContactID | AccountID | attribute |
| --- | --- | --- |
| sksksksk | 111111 | six |

DE 2

| ContactID | AccountID | Cohort |
| --- | --- | --- |
| sksksksk | 111111 | six |

Now I want to write a SQL query to get all records from DE1 which are not in DE2. In my case in both the DEs, ContactID and AccountID are composite primary key.

I have done the left exclusion joins before only with one primarykeys.

Thanks

Comment: Can you please provide an example of the value of your composite PKs and what is the exact problem you faced when doing LEFT JOIN in your case?

Comment: ContactID and the AccountID both are marked as primary key in the data extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would do it similarly as you would have done it with just one Primary Key, just mentioning in the `INNER JOIN` 2 PKs and then also 2 PKs in the `WHERE` clause -

```
SELECT
a.ContactID,
a.AccountID,
a.attribute,
b.Cohort
FROM [Data_Extension_1] a
LEFT JOIN [Data_Extension_2] b ON a.ContactID = b.ContactID AND a.AccountID = b.AccountID
WHERE b.ContactID IS NULL AND b.AccountID IS NULL
```